# Swift: How can i add a shadow to UITabBarController without topBorder

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a little shadow behind my TabBar.

For this case, i use my custom TabBarControllerClass. It looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class EventTabBar: UITabBarController {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 79/255, green: 122/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 198/255, green: 203/255, blue: 209/255, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.isTranslucent = false

    let topBorder = CALayer()
    topBorder.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 0.0)
    topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor


    tabBar.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
    tabBar.clipsToBounds = true

    //Add Shadow to TabBar
    tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.12
    tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 20
    tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
   }


}
```

The Shadow is displayed, but the little black Border on the Top of the TabBar will be displayed again. So i created the CALayer `topBorder` to hide them. But the CALayer no longer works, when using the shadow too.

How can i solve the problem, to display the Shadow and hide the default little black border on top of the TabBar?

Many Thanks for your answer

Comment: It will be better if you create a custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem. To display the shadow and hide the default little top Border you should set the shadowImage and backgroundImage to a empty UIImage:

```
tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

you don't need a CALayer...

Comment: Yes, ma man! Great answer without the need to create a custom tab bar.